# How do I align the items in my form so the questions are on the left while options are on the right

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment

I am trying to create a form and I need to align the information in it such that the questions are aligned on the left while the options are aligned on the right.

I've played around with the id, centering it and moving it left and right.

```css
#wholeform {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 2.0;
  border-radius: 7px;

}
#title {
   max-width: 400px;
  margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
#survey-form {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div id="wholeform">
<p id="description">Let us know how we can improve freeCodeCamp<p>

  <form id="survey-form">
    * Name: <input type="text" name="fullname"><br>
  * Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    * Age: <input type="text" name="age"><br>
    Which option best describes your current role?<select name="status">
  <option value="student">Student</option>
  <option value="full time job">Full Time Job</option>
  <option value="full time learner">Full Time Learner</option>
  <option value="Prefer not to say">Prefer not to say</option>
   <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select><br>
    * How likely is that you would recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?<br>
    <input type="radio"> Definitely<br>
    <input type="radio"> Maybe</br>
    <input type="radio">Not sure</br>
    What do you like most in FCC:<select name="options">
   <option value="challenges">Challenges</option>
    <option value="projects">Projects</option>
    <option value="community">Community</option>
    <option value="open source">Open Source</option></select></br>
    Things that should be improved in the future(Check all that apply)<input type="checkbox" name="front-end" value="Front-end Projects"> Front-end Projects</br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Back-end Projects" value="Back-end Projects" checked> Back-end Projects</br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Data Visualization" value="Data Visualization" checked> Data Visualization</br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Challenges" value="Challenges" checked> Challenges</br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Open Source Community" value="Open Source Community" checked> Open Source Community</br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Gitter help rooms" value="Gitter help rooms" checked> Gitter help rooms</br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Videos" value="Videos" checked> Videos</br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="City Meetups" value="City Meetups" checked> City Meetups</br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Wiki" value="Wiki" checked> Wiki</br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Forum" value="Forum" checked> Forum</br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="Additional Courses" value="Additional Courses" checked> Additional Courses</br>
   Any Comments or Suggestions?<name="comments" id="comments">
Enter your comment here...
</textarea><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </div>
```

Expected results questions on left options on right

Comment: First, please be aware that you have numerous syntactical errors in your HTML (like `</br>` and `<name>` not being valid tags). Second, what do you consider to be questions and what do you consider to be options? I assume an option is anything in an `<option>` tag, and a question is anything not?

Comment: Thank you for letting me know my errors. The options are in the option and input tags. While the questions come before them

Answer (score 0):

I have added a below snippet for you to create a layout for your requirement i.e. questions on one side and answers on other. Please check and confirm if this is what you are wondering for.
Note : Please fill in rest of the details.

```css
#wholeform {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  /* text-align: center; */
  vertical-align: top;
  /* line-height: 2.0; */
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 50px;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.col {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.col-sm-5 {
  flex: 0 0 41.666667%;
  max-width: 41.666667%;
}

.col-sm-7 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 58.333333%;
  flex: 0 0 58.333333%;
  max-width: 58.333333%;
}

#title {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#survey-form {
  /* text-align: center */
}
```

```html
<div id="wholeform">
  <p id="description">Let us know how we can improve freeCodeCamp
    <p>

      <form id="survey-form">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">* Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticName" value="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">* Email</label>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" value="email@example.com">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="staticAge" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">* Age</label>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticAge" value="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="staticSelect" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">* Which option best describes your current role?</label>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <select id="staticSelect" class="form-control" name="status">
              <option value="student">Student</option>
              <option value="full time job">Full Time Job</option>
              <option value="full time learner">Full Time Learner</option>
              <option value="Prefer not to say">Prefer not to say</option>
              <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="staticSelect2" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">* How likely is that you would recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?</label>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <select id="staticSelect2" class="form-control" name="status">
              <option value="student">Student</option>
              <option value="full time job">Full Time Job</option>
              <option value="full time learner">Full Time Learner</option>
              <option value="Prefer not to say">Prefer not to say</option>
              <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-5 pt-0">Radios</legend>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios1" value="option1" checked>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
            First radio
          </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios2" value="option2">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
            Second radio
          </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check disabled">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios3" value="option3" disabled>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
            Third disabled radio
          </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
</div>
```